# Find $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{a_{k}}{s_{k-1}s_{k}}$ if $s_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\langle a_{n}\rangle$ be an increasing sequence of positive real numbers such that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_{k}}$ is divergent. Let $s_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}, n=1,2,3,4,\ldots$ and $t_{n}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{a_{k}}{s_{k-1}s_{k}}$ for $n=2,3,4,\ldots$. Then find $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_{n}$?

Answer (score 4):

hint
$$\dfrac{a_{k}}{s_{k-1}s_{k}}=\dfrac{s_{k}-s_{k-1}}{s_{k}s_{k-1}}=\left(\dfrac{1}{s_{k-1}}-\dfrac{1}{s_{k}}\right),k\ge 2$$

Comment: yes..got the answer.thanku..